What is the difference between `transfer::share_object` vs `transfer::public_share_object` in Sui Move?
What is the difference between transfer::share_object vs transfer::public_share_object in Sui Move?
I need to create a shared object which can be only modified in the same package but others cannot modify.
The explanation from Sui documentation is not clear for me.
